# No fullscreen with UIImage within UIScrollView with iPhone X and up

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

No fullscreen with UIImage within UIScrollView with iPhone X and up. Working perfect with iPhone 8 and +.

Screenshots from Xcode.
['UIImage is the color red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRxE6.png)
[UIScrollView is the color green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYVle.png)

Both UIScrollView and UIImage have constraints to SuperView. But with iPhone X the UIImage don´t align to the SuperView. If I move the UIImage directly to the View then it looks ok but then my Zoom option stop working.

This is the code for Zoom option.

```
func updateZoomFor(size: CGSize) {
        let widthScale = size.width / image2.bounds.width
        let heightScale = size.height / image2.bounds.height
        let scale = min(widthScale,heightScale)
        scrollView2.minimumZoomScale = scale
        scrollView2.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView2.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
        scrollView2.contentSize = .init(width: 2000, height: 2000)
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView2: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return image2
    }
```

This is the code to hide statusbar and home button.

```
 override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
```

I want the UIScrollView and UIImage to work with fullscreen on any Iphone both in portrait and landscape mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- set your scrollView:

```
let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear
        return scrollView
    }()
```

2.- add to the subView:

```
private func setSubviews() {

        self.addSubview(scrollView)

}
```

3.- Add everything to the ScrollView-Subview
example:

```
self.addSubview(scrollView)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(screenIcon)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(screenTitle)
```

4.- set constraints:

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 2),
            ])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I´m new to Swift and I have to review your code. But basically you mean that I have to make my UIScrollView and UIImage programmatically?

Comment: @Ola no, if you want to do it using Stoyboard just set the constraints to the safeArea, and set the height and width the same size as the screen

Comment: It is hard for a beginner use programmatically Views, but it is way better do it and more easy, just research about it and you will get it :D

Comment: You have to set the ScrollView all the way back and set your buttons, uitext upon the scrollView

Comment: ok, I set the constraints to the safeArea but the safeArea is smaller than the screen. What do you mean by set the height and width as the same size as the screen. I want this to work on older iPhones and Iphone X´s. What I'm after is the same function as the app Pictures on Iphone. View a image and zoom in fullscreen.